# how to import ZXING library in android application?

Tags: java, android, zxing

I need to implement ZXING QR code scanner in my application.
I have complete source code for ZXING Android.
Now, I want to use this in my application.
my question is that should I copy all ZXING library code in my application including manifest,xml and java files or I can have a jar file which I need to just add in my application? 
Can anybody tell me how to create jar file from android code, or is any ZXING jar already available which I can just include in my application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/

Thats a step by step guide to natively integrating.  It integrates the zxing project into yours as a backup of sorts.  You will send out an intent request, but your application is registered as a receiver of that request.  If the user doesn't have a different scanner, yours will be the only option.  If they have other scanners it will allow the user to choose.  If you want your app to always be chosen without another option, the comments in the tutorial detail how to change the intent filter to do it.

Keep in mind this is the quick and dirty way to do it.  As others have mentioned, ZXing provides a great tutorial on how to send a barcode intent out and point them to the market if they don't have a scanner.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to do is scan a barcode...then you can simply do it via intents. 
Check [this](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent) page for a tutorial on scanning via intents.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. the first line of the link you provided says that "If the Barcode Scanner is installed on your Android device, you can have it scan for you and return the result " , But I need to consider scenario where zxing barcode application is not already installed on android device. I don't want to force user to install barcode scanner saperately.

Comment: Try this link...http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/DeveloperNotes

    That way you can integrate it as a part of your app. There is also a way of checking if an application is present on your upon installation and at runtime as well...I can't recollect those now, so Google is your friend.

Comment: @krishna5688: Word of advice...read up the wiki on the ZXing site before asking questions on StackOverflow. A lot of what you are asking is already present on the wiki. The StackOverflow community is always more responsive to a specific query. It's hard for someone to outline everything for you here.

Answer (score 1):

In Zing library you only need the `android/` and the `core/ projects` . `ZXING library` code doesn't have `core.jar` file.
You have to create `core.jar file manually from the command line` only (can be a ​bit tricky) so `download core.jar alone` from this link

> [core.3.2.0 download](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/core/3.2.0)

then need to add the `core.jar` file into our project.

add this dependency in `app level gradle`

> 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'

**REFERENCE site**

> [Integrate zxing barcode](https://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/)

[QR code using ZXing library](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/09/android-generate-qr-code-using-zxing.html)

Answer (score 0):

You would never want to copy the `android/` code completely. If anything, you want to compile the `core/` code, and place the resulting `core.jar` in your project's `libs/` folder. Then, you have access to the core scanning code in your project.

But, it is far easier to integrate via Intent as Archit says.

Comment: It may sound foolish for you, but can you please provide me any steps to compile  /core and creating core.jar file. I am using eclipse IDE for developing this application. If you have any link containing steps for it then please share it.

Comment: Erm, just run "ant" in the core/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project in github which was embedded in an android application and it is compatible as android studio project;

https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded

If you live a problem about gradle when you run above project, you can use below project which is same project but there is not any issue about gradle file;

https://bitbucket.org/_oguzhan/ocrandroid